# How to combine with openvpn, dynamic-ip?

Tags: networking, openvpn

I am currently using openvpn to surf online to bypass censorship.

Let me show you the initial scenario:
before openvpn is turned on:
IP: 1.2.3.4 (hypothetical, checked by visiting whatismyip.com/)

after openvpn is turned on
IP: 10.2.3.4 (this is also checked with whatismyip.com/, I assume this is where the vpn's exit point's IP )

Situation: Once I enable openvpn, I can still ssh into this computer by sshing into 1.2.3.4, even though visiting whatismyip.com/ says it's 10.2.3.4. However, I am on dynamic IP, I run a website, and am using tools (inadyn in particular) which pings the freedns.afraid.org (my dns server) and updates my ip.

The messed up part is when inadyn does so, my dns changes the ip to 10.2.3.4, which is presumably the exit point of my vpn.

How do I get around this? (Note that sshing into 1.2.3.4 STILL works).

Answer (score 1):

You could probably add an entry to the routing tables of your OS so that traffic to freedns.afraid.org doesn't go via the VPN.

In order to give any more detailed instructions we'd need to know what OS you're using and what the rest of your network setup looks like.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, a host route pointing at the IP# (or maybe several IP#'s) of freedns.afraid.org should likely be enough to solve the issue.

As it is right now, inadyn (like any other program on your computer) uses the default gateway, which, when the VPN comes up, is through the VPN tunnel.